# Can I use the pipe operator as an OR statement?

Tags: bash, shell, case, glob

Im reading an introductory book on shell commands and it suggests using a pipe command as an OR statement like below:

```
case "$1" in 
  start|START)
    /usr/bin/sshd
    ;;
  stop|STOP)
    kill $(cat/var/run/sshd.pid)
    ;;
esac
```

Why does this work/what is the logic behind it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is not the pipe operator. It is within the `case` syntax. Read `man bash` and go to the "Compound Commands" sections and read about the case.

Here is the extract of what the bash manual has to say

> ```
> case word in [ [(] pattern [ | pattern ] ... ) list ;; ] ... esac
> ```
>
> A `case` command first
>   expands *`word`*, and tries to match it against each *`pattern`* in
>   turn, using the same matching rules as for pathname expansion (see
>   Pathname Expansion below). The word is expanded using  tilde 
>   expansion,  parameter  and  variable expansion, arithmetic
>   substitution, command substitution, process substitution and quote
>   removal. Each *`pattern`* examined is expanded using tilde expansion,
>   parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic substitution, command
>   substitution, and process substitution.  If the shell option
>   `nocasematch` is enabled, the match is performed without regard to the
>   case of alphabetic characters.  When a match  is found, the
>   corresponding *`list`* is executed.  If the `;;` operator is used, no
>   subsequent matches are attempted after the first pattern match.  Using
>   `;&` in place of `;;` causes execution to continue with the *`list`*
>   associated with the next set of patterns.  Using `;;&` in place of
>   `;;` causes the shell to test the next pattern list in the statement,
>   if any, and execute any associated *`list`* on a successful match. 
>   The exit status is zero  if  no pattern matches.  Otherwise, it is the
>   exit status of the last command executed in *`list`*.

This is the syntax

`case word in [ [(] pattern [ | pattern ] ... ) list ;; ] ... esac`

Which is

```
case "$1" in
start|START)
```

matches the above syntax which tells at-least one pattern, or more than one separated by a `|` , a vertical bar.

Answer (score 0):

As phoxis commented, while it is the same character as that used for pipes, in this context it is part of the special syntax of the `case` statement to define more than one value that will cause execution of the following statements (up to the `;;` delimiter).